# Python while loop for validating input

Tags: python, while-loop

I am very new to Python (started 3 days ago) and I am trying to make a loop where whenever the user inputs an invalid input, the code will respond and tell them to reenter their response but I cannot seem to get it.

```
while sub1!= "A,B,C,D,F":
      print("Invalid Entry,try again:")
```

Comment: I suppose you want the user input to be any of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `F`. Then change while loop to `while sub1 not in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "F"):`

Comment: what is invalid input in your case?

Comment: please add your  invalid input

Answer (score 1):

The user_inputs list and the for loop is to simulate different user inputs.

```
user_inputs = ['G','H','I','A','C']

for i in range(len(user_inputs)):
    # if user input is not in the list print valid (or do whatever you want to do)
    while user_inputs[i] not in ['A','B','C','D','F']:
        i+=1
        print('valid input')
    # if user input is in the list, then print invalid input... and break out of the loop
    else:
        print('invalid input')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if also to check condition

```
sub1 = "Z"
if not sub1 in ['A','B','C','D','F']:
..print("Invalid Entry,try again:")
```

Comment: OP wants the user to retry in case of invalid input. So a loop will be better

Comment: OP wants an iterative solution not a if condition

Answer (score 0):

using `while` loop and `try-except`:

```
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input()

        if user_input in "A, B, C, D, F".split(','):
            print("Valid Entry")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid entry please try again")
    except ValueError:
        print("Provide A or B or C or D or F")
        continue
```